# Why is Visual Studio telling me that netstandard2.1 is incompatible with netcoreapp2.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an old netcoreapp2.1 targeted project that cannot be upgraded. I am developing a (somewhat universal) class library for it and some other projects to use and I have published it to Azure DevOps private artifact storage.

According to MSDN, .NET Standard 2.1 should support .NET Core 2.1:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0

However, as soon as I attempt to add my library to my .NET Core 2.1 project, Visual Studio says:

```
Error   NU1202  Package My.Contracts 0.0.1.117 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package My.Contracts 0.0.1.117 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
```

I tried Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 - the same results. What's going on? Is MSDN lying or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can always do multi-targetting. In your csproj file have `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>`. This will generate 2 dlls that can be bundled in your nuget package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information seems to be wrong. The page [.NET Standard versions](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/dotnet-standard#versions) says that .NET Standard 2.1 is supported since .NET Core 3.0

Comment: The latest change, on 2022-01-25, introduced the tabs and has a copy/paste mistake. It's only been wrong for a few days.